# Is there a way to change Github Action event name in between?

Tags: github, github-actions, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I am working on a feature where I have an Github action that triggers on `issue_comment` events.
But inside that i am using pre-commit.ci-lite which is suppose to run on `pull_request` events only(It is their internal implementation).
So what i want is to trigger my workflow by `issue_comment` only, but before the runner takes pre-commit.ci-lite i want to trick the runner into believing that the event is `pull_request` and not `issue_comment`, just the github.event_name should be `pull_request` instead of `issue_comment`

I am aware that i can use pre-commit.ci (non lite) for this. But I dont want to do that.

May anyone help me with this??

I tried the following way, but it didn't worked

```
- name: Change Event name
  run: |
      github.event_name = pull_request
```

I know this is dumb

Comment: this is a terrible idea